# Select object under object in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, selections

I want to be able to select objects under other objects in Inkscape.

After watching a few tutorials I noticed that designers achieve this by clicking at the place where the object is under another object while using a selector tool and pressing `Alt`. I tried it and it did not work out. What may I have missed while doing the procedure?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

At the last screenshot I am pressing `Alt`, using the selector tool and click at the place where the ellipse is under the rectangle. But I end up with a rectangle being chosen.

I noticed that clicking twice, while pressing `Alt` does the job. Is it supposed to be so? Should I always click twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Alt-click</kbd> will select deeper objects each time.

So if you have nothing selected, the first <kbd>Alt-click</kbd> will select the top-most object. Then the second lowest, then the third, etc.

So your *double click* may be actually selecting the rectangle and then the ellipse.

If you need to select hidden objects regularly, you may want to switch to outline view (*View -> Display mode -> Outline*). Here you see the outline of all objects, and directly select the one you wish.

Comment: Oh! Using outline for the purpose is the best idea I have ever heard! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Objects panel shows all layers and objects as an ordered list. You can select any object by clicking it in the list.

Other useful functionality:

- hiding and locking objects
- renaming (right-click an object)
- adjusting opacity
- changing blending mode
- blurring
- changing the order
- moving from a layer to another

+more

The panel launcher is in Object menu.